# Creating a cron job in php

Tags: php, cron

I want to create a cron job which has to execute a file every 30 minutes or regular interval. I don't have a cpanel or any front-end to do that.

How do I do it?

Comment: Dupe: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+cron

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803631/is-there-any-way-to-automatically-run-php-script-on-hosting-web-server-withour-cr has some good solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.  This is an OS level function not PHP level.  Best bet is to email your host and ask them if it's possible to setup a cron for you.

Comment: But, i think it can be done by
http://joomlapanel.com/joomla-article/joomla-tutorial/258-setup-cron-job-for-your-joomla-site.html
correct me if i'm wrong, please.

Comment: @Sam Read further. It tells you how to set up Joomla's cron on the OS level, but you still need OS-level access to do so.

Comment: @Sam - that article specifically mentions that you may have to have your server hosts set up crons for you.  It all depends on your hosting plan and what tools you have.

Answer (score 0):

[Psuedocron](http://www.bitfolge.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=61:php&catid=38:eigene&Itemid=59&limitstart=3) may help.

Answer (score 0):

If the user as whom the webserver runs is allowed to have cron jobs, and the system is correcty set up, then its simply a matter of executing the cron program (popen, exec, system....etc) and feeding it an appropirate input file. However on any sensibly configured, internet connected webserver, the httpd user will NOT be allowed to run cron jobs.

There are tools like pseudocron but be careful.

C.