# How To Schedule Task With PHP?

Tags: php, cron, task, schedule

How to develop a schedule task system like the one used by Wordpress to schedule post? Do they use Cron Job? If they use it, how they configure it through PKP script?

Comment: Closely related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - good cronjob/crontab/cron tutorial or book.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959099/php-good-cronjob-crontab-cron-tutorial-or-book)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, WordPress just sets the publish date to some time in the future. It doesn't actually cause an event to happen in the future, it just looks that way when someone views the site.

You'd need a cron job if you actually wanted to do something in the future, web servers only respond to requests made by user agents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cron` and in iterations get run `php_cli` interpreter with your script.

Answer (score 0):

I use php cron tasks, they look like the following

```
0 0 * * * * php -f /var/www/public_html/mycronphpfile.php
```

This means, at midnight, every day, run the command line php and execute the specified file.

Comment: This will require php-cli package installed.

Comment: In case someone wonders about the series of values in th answer. It follows the format: minute(0-59) hour(0-23) day(1-31) month(1-12) weekday(0-6) command. Asterik means every one of them.

So the command means 0th minute 0th hour every day every month every weekday, run this file.