# How do I hook into an event triggered once a MySQL query is true?

Tags: php, mysql, perl

How does one create a PHP script that checks the MySQL row consistently and if a set query is matched, it starts an event, such as sending an email?

For example, on query match `Fire` start email:

```
To: me@me.com
From: php@trigger.com
Subject: Set query met, auto email complete.
```

It would be around MySQL5. I'm stuck on this. Am I best to do it in Perl or similar?
Perhaps it could also email various users? (This isn't the hard bit. :P)

Comment: you need a cron job. Can you set some up where you're hosted?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803631/is-there-any-way-to-automatically-run-php-script-on-hosting-web-server-withour-cr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `cron` or similar scheduler involves *polling*, which works but is [brute force and ignorance](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/brute-force-and-ignorance.html). I can't recommend it: there's a time delay between when the row changes and when cron executes the checking program; repeated checking is a waste of resources.

The elegant solution is database trigger, see [Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) and [Can triggers call an external application through a UDF?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-23-5-1-13). You will get an event whenever your table row is on fire or something, and your email sending program is called immediately.

If you want to use Perl, [`Email::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/Email::Simple)/[`Email::Sender`](http://p3rl.org/Email::Sender) is nifty.

Comment: Sweet, thanks daxim. Exact answer I wanted, shall try it out in a few hours :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP or Perl or any other programming language you like.

Create a cronjob to execute your script every X hours.

For example `php queryDatabase.php`.

That's it.

Comment: I'm aware of CRON, very useful tool :-)

What about the content in the actual script? Can someone just give me an idea on where I start?

Never done an email/trigger script before. Only done MySQL queries :-)