# Is there a way to watch a mysql database for changes using perl?

Tags: mysql, database, perl, inotify

I'm looking for a solution similar to the inotify method of watching files for changes. I'm aware that I could watch the binlog file of the mysql database and run queries to pick out the new results but that seems very inefficient and inelegant; as does simply doing masses of queries in a loop waiting for new results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501346/how-do-i-hook-into-an-event-triggered-once-a-mysql-query-is-true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to the table(s) you're interested in, you can use that to alert the watching application. You could do that in a number of ways:

1. Create an audit table in the database, and have the trigger write the relevant info there; and have your watching application poll the audit table for new entries. You're still polling, but in a controlled way which won't hit the server too hard.
2. Have the trigger [call an external app](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10) through a UDF.

Comment: That's what [I commented already 6 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4418598#comment-4820725) as already existing answer. Enjoy your bounty.

Comment: FWIW, I added this answer before I'd noticed your comment (which I did upvote); and the first of my suggested solutions is different from yours. I genuinely wasn't plagiarising.

Comment: @daxim: If you wanted the bounty - you should have posted your comment as an answer! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as MyISAM tables go you can watch `information_schema.TABLES.UPDATE_TIME`. That would save you from polling all tables you're interested in. For InnoDB, watching binlog is the best I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to do a push/signal instead of a DB poll. Have whatever process updates the database, notify your Perl code that an update was done via any IPC you pick (heck, a log file being appended to with name of table being changed might do the trick well enough).

This is especially effective if the updates a fairly rare/low volume yet the reaction time to them must be quick.

An additional benefit is portability - works for any MySQL backend or for any other DB engine.

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option as the database is updated by some other 3rd party program I am using and the perl script I am writing does not do the updating of the database.