# Push functionality from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have a python application.
I wanted to know whether there is any functionality(i.e. event or trigger) in mysql which will allow me to notify my python application when data is inserted in the database.
I would like to avoid the use of polling because it will cause a large overhead on my database.

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly for Python,but [Is there a way to watch a mysql database for changes using perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418598/is-there-a-way-to-watch-a-mysql-database-for-changes-using-perl) gives two option how to do that:

> 1.Create an audit table in the database, and have the trigger write the relevant info there; and have your watching application poll the audit table for new entries. You're still polling, but in a controlled way which won't hit the server too hard.
>
> 2.Have the trigger call an external app through a UDF.